# Indent XML in JEditorPane

Tags: java, xml, swing, sax

I am trying to indent XML in a Java JEditorPane, so that this:

```
<mytag>
<tag1>
</tag1>
</mytag>
```

becomes:

```
<mytag>
    <tag1>
    </tag1>
</mytag>
```

I have tried constructing a DocumentBuilder object, and then transforming it with:

```
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")
serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
```

then set the text in the JEditorPane:

```
editorPane.setText(do serialization and transformation methods here)
```

It does not indent the XML however..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: When you print out the transformed XML, is it correctly indented?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this to format XML: http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't need the level of sophistication that this provides. A simple pretty print does the job.